# Multiple Route is consuming messages sequentially in apache camel 4.x , but its consuming parallel in camel 2.x

Tags: apache-camel, spring-jms, spring-camel

We have multiple jms route defined in same route class. All the route is having more than 100 messages in activemq broker. In earlier version of camel (2.x), we can see the messages has been consumed parallely by all the defined route if the messages are available.
But in camel 4.x , we can see the second route is consuming messages after completing the first route messages.

Please see the route example we using

```
from("jms:queue:A")
  .bean("insertToATable)
  .wireTap("jms:queue:B");

from("jms:queue:B")
   .bean("insertToBTable)
   .wireTap("jms:queue:C")

from("jms:queue:C")
   .bean("insertToCTable)
   .end();
```

Here we are loading 500 messages to queue A and its pushing to queue B. But queue B is waiting for to complete all the messages from queue A and started consuming.
We want the queue B needs to consume messages as soon as it get. So all the route can process parallel. How we can achieve this camel 4.x?

Comment: If I had to guess, it seems that you had message prefetching disabled and have somehow re-enabled message prefetching.  With the prefetching mechanism, only the last message is acknowledged.  In your case, you would be reading 100 messages, but if none of those messages have been acknowledged, then they would not be available yet on the other destination.